# Choosing a Design Pattern For my Specification

Tags: java, php, mysql, design-patterns

I have a Specification which goes like this:

say I have a Product which has some set of features

```
Product (Base Product)
-> Feature 1
-> Feature 2
-> Feature 3
-> ......
-> Feature N
```

Now I want to create derived Products as below:

```
Derived Product 1
-> Feature 1
-> Feature 2
...........
-> Feature M

Derived Product 2
-> Feature 1
-> Feature 3
...........
-> Feature X

Derived Product 3
-> Feature 2
-> Feature 3
...........
-> Feature Y
```

The N number of features actually represent rows in database table And a Derived Product is a Combination of Multiple Features from Base Product.

Can anybody please suggest me some kind of design pattern to follow for creating table in database and writing code to solve this problem?

I went through Specification Design Pattern But it does not exactly fit.

Thanks in advance for your answer.

Comment: What **is** the problem?

Comment: I need some suggestions to get it solved in a efficient way.

Comment: How to solve **WHAT** exactly?

Comment: I have N number of features in a Product and they represent rows in database table, my objective is to create Derived Product which is a Combination of Multiple Features from Base Product. i want suggestions on how do i do it.

Comment: Create **how**? What is the logic for including features into your Derived Product?

Comment: I choose Feature to include or not to include while creating Derived Product. Since features comes in from the database row. How can i handle them?

Comment: Your feature sounds more like an attribute ? .. Value , Name / Code pair ?

Comment: How do you chose: via user interface, based on some internal logic, combination of both? Are all base features applicable to every derived product?  Design Patterns are just widely accepted  solutions and best practices for particular problems.  Again, what are you solving here?

Comment: Yes, The Features are Value at the moment.

Comment: How do you chose: via user interface **yes**
Are all base features applicable to every derived product? **no at many times**

Comment: The usual way is to create a Name , Value, Code -> table  and then a configuration table which links a code to a converter , Int , Long , String but That then makes your domain model troublesome.

Comment: On a pure, "what the question asked" principle, perhaps http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern

Comment: @EvanKnowles Composite Pattern seems to be useful in this case, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although @Evan Knowles has a good point with the *Composite_pattern* from *Structural* side. Another possible solution can be [Factory Method](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/factory_method) from *Creational* side. Since it allows you to create an instance of several derived classes. Also defines an interface for creating an object, but let subclasses decide which class to instantiate. Factory Method lets a class defer instantiation to subclasses.

I think that what is this question all about (maybe I'm wrong) is said here:

> some kind of design pattern to follow for creating table in database and writing code

So If I'm correct, what you need is more [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping)-related. But you need to know why you want to add abstraction on top of JDBC. If just derivation is the main problem then you can consider paying more attention to your Model and less to organizing the DB tables.

Both ways - this [list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_object-relational_mapping_software) will be helpful (under *Java* section).

Comment: Thanks for your insight regarding usage of Factory Method and overall suggestion for the problem.